# MySQL: How to add a column for original_id?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I want to add a column `original_id` to existing table, for example **table_1**:

| sub_id | next_sub_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 6 | null |
| 8 | 10 |
| 10 | null |

to **table_2** as `sub_id = 4 or sub_id = 6` belongs to the first one that `sub_id = 2`
and `sub_id = 10` belongs to `sub_id = 8`

| sub_id | next_sub_id | original_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 6 | 2 |
| 6 | null | 2 |
| 8 | 10 | 8 |
| 10 | null | 8 |

How can I query under MySQL? Thanks!

Comment: Which exact version of MySQL?

Comment: @stickybit it was 5.7

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/) for more detail information

sameple is like this

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD [COLUMN] column_name column_definition [FIRST|AFTER existing_column];
```

then you can [update](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-data.aspx) the value in the new column
sample is like this

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_name 
SET 
    column_name1 = expr1,
    column_name2 = expr2,
    ...
[WHERE
    condition];
```

Comment: thanks. I guess table_2 is a temp table that we want to obtain it from query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE for this:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select sub_id, next_sub_id, sub_id as original_id, 1 as lev
      from t
      where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.next_sub_id = t.sub_id)
      union all
      select t.sub_id, t.next_sub_id, cte.original_id, lev + 1
      from t join
           cte
           on cte.next_sub_id = t.sub_id
     )
select *
from cte
order by sub_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=664211eb1e3a649fbf77f40528575a6d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. It worked on the link you provided for MySQL 8.0. Unfortunately current version is 5.7 that doesn't support that function.

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi . . . There is no simple way to do this in MySQL 5.7.  You either need to know the maximum depth or use a stored procedure.